# How to return a list from python callable to the dag?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to use a python operator to fetch a list of filenames that have the run date string in it and then download these files using the sftp-to-s3 operator. Is there a better way to do this? With this following code I get the error > **name ti not found**

```
def get_files(**kwargs):

    sftp_hook = SFTPHook(ftp_conn_id='conn')
    str_date = kwargs["date"]
    files = []
    with sftp_hook.get_conn() as conn:
        for entry in conn.listdir_attr():
            mode = entry.st_mode
            if S_ISREG(mode) and str_date in entry.filename:
                files.append(entry.filename)
    return files -> list of files to download 


with dag:

   date = '{{ next_ds_nodash }}'
   source_files = PythonOperator(task_id=f"get_files",
                                 python_callable=get_files,
                                 op_kwargs={'date': {date}},
                                 provide_context=True,
                                 dag=dag)

   file_list = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_files', key='files')

   collect = []
   for file in file_list:
       op = SFTPToS3Operator(task_id=f"download_{file}",
                             sftp_conn_id="conn",
                             sftp_path=f"path1/{file}" if 'key' in file else f"path2/{file}",
                             s3_conn_id=aws_conn_id,
                             s3_bucket=s3_bucket,
                             s3_key =f"/temp/{date}/{file}",
                             dag=dag)

      collect.append(op)
   collect.set_upstream(source_files)
```

Comment: You can't call `file_list = ti.xcom_pull`outside of an operator.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [XCOM Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms), XCOMs are similar to [Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#variables) and therefore must be serialized and deserialized. Use `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` to do so.

Additionally you shoul be using the xcom pull inside another task instead of in the DAG definition itself.

The DAG should only be calls to various task_ids. Perform all operations within tasks and chain them together in the DAG.

Here is an [example of the proper use of XCOMs](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py).

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

dag = DAG(
    'example_xcom',
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    default_args={'owner': 'airflow'},
    tags=['example'],
)

value_1 = [1, 2, 3]
value_2 = {'a': 'b'}


def push(**kwargs):
    """Pushes an XCom without a specific target"""
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='value from pusher 1', value=value_1)


def push_by_returning(**kwargs):
    """Pushes an XCom without a specific target, just by returning it"""
    return value_2


def puller(**kwargs):
    """Pull all previously pushed XComs and check if the pushed values match the pulled values."""
    ti = kwargs['ti']

    # get value_1
    pulled_value_1 = ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='push')
    if pulled_value_1 != value_1:
        raise ValueError(f'The two values differ {pulled_value_1} and {value_1}')

    # get value_2
    pulled_value_2 = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_by_returning')
    if pulled_value_2 != value_2:
        raise ValueError(f'The two values differ {pulled_value_2} and {value_2}')

    # get both value_1 and value_2
    pulled_value_1, pulled_value_2 = ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids=['push', 'push_by_returning'])
    if pulled_value_1 != value_1:
        raise ValueError(f'The two values differ {pulled_value_1} and {value_1}')
    if pulled_value_2 != value_2:
        raise ValueError(f'The two values differ {pulled_value_2} and {value_2}')


push1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=push,
)

push2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_by_returning',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=push_by_returning,
)

pull = PythonOperator(
    task_id='puller',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=puller,
)

pull << [push1, push2]
```